# Issue with the delete method of a Binary Search Tree in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I am trying to learn the implementation of a Binary Search Tree in Python with the help of the following link [Binary Search Tree in Python](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/binary-search-tree-library-in-python/)

I am unable to implement the deletion method properly.

Here's my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

def Insert_BTreeNode(self,data):
    if self.data:
        if data<self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left=Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.Insert_BTreeNode(data)

        elif data>self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right=Node(data)

            else:
                self.right.Insert_BTreeNode(data)

    else:
        self.data=data

def Lookup(self,data,parent=None):

    if data<self.data:
        if self.left is None:
            return None,None
        return self.left.Lookup(data,self)
    elif data>self.data:
        if self.right is None:
            return None,None
        return self.right.Lookup(data,self)
    else:
        print(self.data,parent.data)



def Children_count(self):
    count=0

    if self.left:
        count+=1
    if self.right:
        count+=1

    print(count)

def Delete(self,data):
    children_count=0
    node=self.Lookup(data)
    parent=None

    if node is not None:
        children_count=node.Children_count()

    if children_count==0:
        if parent:
            if parent.left is Node:
                parent.left=None
            else:
                parent.right=None
            del Node
        else:
            self.data=data

def print_treeInorder(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.print_treeInorder()
    print(self.data)
    if self.right:
        self.right.print_treeInorder()


def print_treePostorder(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.print_treePostorder()
    if self.right:
        self.right.print_treePostorder()
    print(self.data)

def print_treePreorder(self):
    print(self.data)

    if self.left:
        self.left.print_treePreorder()
    if self.right:
        self.right.print_treePreorder()

root=Node(8)
root.Insert_BTreeNode(3)
root.Insert_BTreeNode(10)
root.Insert_BTreeNode(1)
root.Insert_BTreeNode(6)
root.Insert_BTreeNode(4)
root.Insert_BTreeNode(7)
root.Insert_BTreeNode(14)
root.Insert_BTreeNode(13)
root.Delete(13)
root.print_treeInorder()
```

This is kind of like homework so I'd appreciate if people give me solutions related to my code and not external libraries.

Also I'd appreciate if anyone could comment where the code is wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you are missing an else branch in `if children_count == 0`

Comment: second: the function `Lookup()` doesn't return a couple `(parent,self)` when the searched node is found `data==self.data`.

Comment: third: the function `Children_count()` doesn't return `(count)`.

Comment: @Sekuraz I noe it's missing.It's a work in progress.But thanks for mentioning it out.

Comment: @J. Piquard even after correcting the code as per your suggestions,it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are deleting 'Node', this is the class itself. You maybe meant 'node'

Comment: @Sekuraz.I'll check this and let you know.

Comment: And also be aware with case sensitive source: `if parent.left is Node:` shall be `if parent.left is node:` in the `Delete()` before the suggested point of @Sekuraz.

Comment: @DhruvMarwha, when looking at **["Binary Search Tree library in Python"](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/binary-search-tree-library-in-python/)**, the deletion part needs a lot of code to be complete. I have tested partially my own, but the case of toplevel deletion (first node `Node(8)`) is special.

Comment: @DhruvMarwha, be aware with my suggestion for `Lookup()` return. the blog is returning found node first `return self, parent` instead of my `(parent,self)` !!!

Comment: @J.Piquard Thanks for all your suggestions.If I use code from the above link,will my delete function work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow the function `Delete()` of the `class Node` to work properly when using code provided at ["Blog: Binary Search Tree library in Python"](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/binary-search-tree-library-in-python/), it is necessary to correct the following missing and typo errors.

**Step 1** - return the expected couple (node,parent) from the `Lookup()` function.

> As commented above and described in the blog, when finding the node to
>   be removed, the function shall return both node and parent.
>   Don't try to print `parent.data` when parent is still equal to None.

```
def Lookup(self,data,parent=None):
    if data<self.data:
        if self.left is None:
            return (None,None)
        return self.left.Lookup(data,self)
    elif data>self.data:
        if self.right is None:
            return (None,None)
        return self.right.Lookup(data,self)
    else:
        # prevent case of parent is None
        if (parent is not None):
            print(self.data,parent.data)
        # ADDED from blog link
        return (self, parent)
```

**Step 2** - return the number from the `Children_count()` function.

> As commented above and described in the blog, the result of the
>   function `Children_count()` shall be returned to be taken into
>   account.

```
def Children_count(self):
    count=0
    if self.left:
        count+=1
    if self.right:
        count+=1
    print(count)
    # ADDED from link
    return (count)
```

**Step 3** - manage the returned values from `self.Lookup(data)` in the `Delete()` function.

> As commented above and described in the blog, the returned value of
>   `Lookup()` is a couple of nodes.

```
def Delete(self,data):
    children_count=0
    # INSERTED from link
    node, parent = self.Lookup(data)
    ...
```

Instead of:

```
def Delete(self,data):
    children_count=0
    node =self.Lookup(data)
    parent=None
    ...
```

**Step 4** - Python is a case sensitive language, `Node` and `node` are not equivalent.

> As commented above and described in the blog, to call a function of a
>   class, it is necessary to use its instance `node` instead of its class
>   name `Node`.

In the case `if children_count==0:`:

```
if children_count==0:
    print(" - The node to remove has no child.")
    if parent:
        # INSERTED from link
        if parent.left is node:
            parent.left=None
        else:
            parent.right=None
        # INSERTED from link
        del node
    else:
        self.data=data
```

Instead of:

```
if children_count==0:
    if parent:
        if parent.left is Node:
            parent.left=None
        else:
            parent.right=None
        del Node
    else:
        self.data=data
```

**What else ?**

Reuse the source code of blog for both `elif children_count == 1:` (*The node to remove has 1 child.*) and `else:` (*The node to remove has 2 children.*) and the function `Delete()` will work properly.

**Test case 1** - The node to remove has no child.

```
root.Delete(13)
```

**Test case 2** - The node to remove has 1 child.

```
root.Delete(10)
```

**Test case 3** - The node to remove has 2 children.

```
root.Delete(6)
```

**Test case 4** - The node to remove has 2 children and is the root node.

```
root.Delete(8)
```

Comment: Thank you @J.Piquard for all your sugestions.